# Flash AS3 - finding Y position tween object on moving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, transition, tween

My Flash AS3 script as below, my question is how to finding (trace) Y position tween object on moving...

I want the know the position like:
objectA = -50, 0, 25, 50 ... 150, 170, 180, 200, 210 ..., 750, 800.

```
var objTween = new Tween(objectA, "y", Strong.easeOut, -100, 800, 15, true);
objTween.start();
```

Comment: How about listening for the [Tween's MOTION_CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#event:motionChange) event and checking positions in the handler ?

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are looking just to print out the values you can run the tween function directly, which I think is kinda cool

```
for (var i:int=0; i< 15*60; i++) {
    trace (Strong.easeOut(i, -100, 800, 15*60));
}
```

[(Documentation)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/easing/Strong.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE` event which is triggered every time the tweened object has been modified.

([Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#event%3amotionChange))

*Example (untested):*

```
var objTween:Tween = new Tween(objectA, "y", Strong.easeOut, -100, 800, 15, true);
objTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onTweenChange);
objTween.start();
```

*[...]*

```
function onTweenChange(e:TweenEvent):void {
    trace(objectA.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var objTween = new Tween(objectA,"y",Strong.easeOut,-100,800,15,true);
objTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, tweenEvents);
objTween.start();

function tweenEvents(e)
{
    switch (objectA.y)
    {
        case -100 :
            trace("objectA is at -100");
            break;
        case 800 :
            trace("objectA is at 800");
            break;

        default :
            trace(objectA.y);
    }
}
```

I'm a big fan of the switch case statement, simply because they feel cleaner than a series of if else statements... you could do something like `if (objectA.y ==50){trace("at 50")};`

hope that helps :)

Comment: If looking to trigger specific events at specific coords, why not just create a simple conditional that tracks its position...much like above, but is the TweenListener really necessary?

    `if (objectA.x ==50){
        doSomething()
    {`

In my experience its going to know where it is, through the tween, regardless.

I've never used the native Tween class though, and I often opt for Greensock which provides a TON of useful tricks and feedback.

http://www.greensock.com